# Weapon with locked slot

Tags: hyrule-warriors

I recently discovered a weapon with a single slot, but it was locked. Instead of an ability, it has a symbol with crossing swords in it followed by "x 1000".  I am unable to use it in the smith as a base or a source.

What does this mean?  How do I unlock it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You kill that many enemies with that weapon and the ability unlocks. The more you have to kill, the better the ability. You do NOT need to kill them all in one map.

There are three groups of those abilities (x1000, x2000, x3000).

> The Master Sword has a special skill on it. You need to have all 61 weapon types and then you can kill 25,000 enemies over time.

Comment: So the master sword with it's x25000 locked slot requires 25,000 kills in a single map?

Comment: No. You do not need to kill them all in a single map. I think that is literally impossible.